# AWS Simple Email Service Domain Validation and Domain created in Route 53 Private Hosted Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-ses

I created xyz.com in Route 53 Private Hosted Zone. Next AWS Simple Email Service I validated the xyz.com and added the records in Private Zone.
But It is not validating the Domain.
I using this for internal purpose. Could you please guide me why I am not able to validate Domain from SES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private hosted zones are not valid for SES email validation. You can create any private hosted zone for any domain you want. SES validation requires you to prove that you actually own or have administrative control over the domain in question. If you don't actually own the domain then SES will not let you send email using that domain.